# How to display the array of data inside table Using Angular.js ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am facing one issue.I need to display some array of data inside table using Angular.js.I am explaining my code below.

> Table:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Date</td>
                <td rowspan="2">id</td>
                <td rowspan="2">email</td>
                <td colspan="7">Order</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td>Order Id</td>
              <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
   </table>
```

I am explaining my array of data below.

```
$scope.listOfData=
[
    {
        "date": "2016-01-25 18:14:00 to 2016-02-05 11:26:05",
        "id": "36",
        "email": "raj@gmail.com",
        "order": [
            {
                "order_status": 1,
                "order_id": 1111
            },
            {
                "order_status": 0,
                "order_id": 2222
            },
            {
                "order_status": 1,
                "order_id": 5555
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "date": "2016-01-23 13:15:59 to 2016-01-25 18:14:00",
        "id": "37",
        "email": "rahul@gmail.com",
        "order": [
            {
                "order_status": 1,
                "order_id": 3333
            },
            {
                "order_status": 0,
                "order_id": 4444
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to display above data into the table using Angular.js.please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this code and check out the output. Let me know if you need different format.. cheers!!!

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("AppController",['$scope',AppController]);

function AppController($scope) {
  
  
    $scope.listOfData=[
          {
              "date": "2016-01-25 18:14:00 to 2016-02-05 11:26:05",
              "id": "36",
              "email": "raj@gmail.com",
              "order": [
                  {
                      "order_status": 1,
                      "order_id": 1111
                  },
                  {
                      "order_status": 0,
                      "order_id": 2222
                  },
                  {
                      "order_status": 1,
                      "order_id": 5555
                  }
              ]
          },
          {
              "date": "2016-01-23 13:15:59 to 2016-01-25 18:14:00",
              "id": "37",
              "email": "rahul@gmail.com",
              "order": [
                  {
                      "order_status": 1,
                      "order_id": 3333
                  },
                  {
                      "order_status": 0,
                      "order_id": 4444
                  }
              ]
          }
      ];
      
      
    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppController">

  
  <table cellspacing="5px" style="border:1px solid black;">
  <tr >
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>email</th>
        <th>Order</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="orderInfo in listOfData">
        <td>{{orderInfo.date}}</td>
        <td>{{orderInfo.id}}</td>
        <td>{{orderInfo.email}}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <th>Order stat</th>
              <th>Id<th>
            </tr>
            <tr ng-repeat="orderStat in orderInfo.order">
              <td>{{orderStat.order_status}}</td>
              <td>{{orderStat.order_id}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
    </tr>   
    
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<!--
This is for table inside row.
<tr ng-repeat="orderInfo in listOfData">
        <td>{{orderInfo.date}}</td>
        <td>{{orderInfo.id}}</td>
        <td>{{orderInfo.email}}</td>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="orderStat in orderInfo.order">
              <td>{{orderStat.order_status}}</td>
              <td>{{orderStat.order_id}}</td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
        
    </tr>   -->
```

Comment: So you need headers for id and order_status?

Comment: yes i need sub header for `order_status and order_id`.

Comment: Do you want it inside the column or in the place of order? Both can be dont. Your choice. Which one?

Comment: under `order` cilumn there should be two sub column like `orer id and order status` and these should keep multiple value as you have done.

Comment: Check it out now. Is that good enough or no repeating of order stat and id header in each column?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102768/discussion-between-pritesh-and-satya).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,list) in listOfData">
          <td ng-repeat="(key, lists) in list.order "> {{lists.order_status}}</td>
          <td ng-repeat="(key, lists) in list.order "> {{lists.order_id}}</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you header fixed of the table, put it outside of your loop.

Put this outside of the loop i.e **ng-repeat**

```
           <tr>
                <td rowspan="2">Date</td>
                <td rowspan="2">id</td>
                <td rowspan="2">email</td>
                <td colspan="7">Order</td>
            </tr>
```

You don't want to create it for every item, as it's going to be fixed.

Now, iterate through your list of json objects, using ng-repeat, as explained above.

Something like this..

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable" >
   <div ng-repeat="list in listOfData">
    {{list.id}}
     <div ng-repeat="oderlist in list.order">
          {{orderlist.order_id}}
     </div>
</div>
</table>
```

You can modify it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you,

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in listOfData">
<td> 
   <ul>
      <li>
         {{item.order}} // or print your array element there
      </li>
   </ul>
</td>
```